# I need a media-type for text/applescript, but I don't see registered with iana?

Tags: rest, applescript, mime-types

I did a quick scan of iana registered mime-types and didn't see anything specific say a "text/applescript".

Have I missed something?

Or are people using text/plain instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this page which shows the mime type as "application/x-applescript".
http://www.huw.id.au/filetypes.html